# awk for multiple patterns

Tags: awk, if-statement

My file looks like:

```
L   0   256 *   *   *   *   *
H   0   307 100.0   +   0   0
S   30  351 *   *   *   *   *
D   8   27  *   *   *   *   99.3    
C   11  1   *   *   *   *   *
```

for my script I would like to start by awk print $0  for certain lines using $1

Such as

```
awk '{if ($1!="C") {print $0}  else if ($1!="D") {print $0}}'
```

But, there has to be a way to combine "C" and "D" into one IF statement... right?

For example if I want to search for == L,H,S   ie... NOT C or D how would I right this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your present condition is not correct as both `$1!="C"` and `$1!="D"` can't be false at the same time. Hence, it will always print the whole file.

This will do as you described:

```
awk '{if ($1!="C" && $1!="D") {print $0}}'  file
```

Comment: That explains why it would not work while the same statement with multiples truths worked.   My background is biology not CS so I am learning as I go.

Comment: I guess in biology, it's sometimes possible for impossible things to work. :)

Answer (score 8):

Using awk, you can provide rules for specific patterns with the syntax

```
awk 'pattern {action}' file
```

see the [awk manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?awk) for the definition of a pattern. In your case, you could use a regular expression as a pattern with the syntax

```
awk'/regular expression/ {action}' file
```

and a basic regular expression which would suit your needs could be

```
awk '/^[^CD]/ {print $0}' file
```

which you can actually shorten into

```
awk '/^[^CD]/' file
```

since `{print $0}` is the default action, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: That will only work if there's no spaces before $1. Also, you don't need {print $0} as that's the default action.

Comment: Indeed, here `/^[^CD]/` translates into : `/…/` its a pattern, `/^…/` the pattern is at the beginning of the line, `/^[^CD]/` the first letter found should not be a C or a D. Therefore, as you say, this will not work in case any character is placed before the C or the D, and this will also filter out any line starting with a word having C or D as its first letter.

Comment: I know there's a lot of awk books and other documentation that ramble on about "pattern"s (some written by the guys who invented the tool!) but they're wrong - the awk body is made up of <condition> { <action> } segments, not <pattern> { <action> } segments, otherwise how do you explain "x > 2 { print }"? "x > 2" is clearly a condition, not a "pattern". In any case, /.../ is an RE, not a pattern and in that context it's short for $0 ~ /.../ which again is a condition, not a pattern either.

Comment: You are right. I may have used the term “pattern” improperly. According to the awk manual a “pattern” is what you call a `<condition>` in your comment. I'll edit my answer taking your remark into account.

Comment: Right, the awk manual and all awk books I know of are wrong in using the term "pattern" rather than "condition". I think originally the intent of awk was to look for a pattern in some text, hence the original documentation using that term and it's spread to other documentation since, but awk hasn't really had just a "pattern" in that context for 20 years, if even then. Even old, broken awk isn't restricted to just having a "pattern" in that context.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$1 ~ /[CD]/' file

awk '$1 ~ /[LHS]/' file

awk '$1 ~ /[^LHS]/' file

awk '$1 !~ /[LHS]/' file
```

Comment: How come this syntax is so "streamline" or trimmed down? is this style of scripting called something else? If so I like to learn its rules.  Thank you!

Comment: It's nothing fancy. Awk is made up of <condition> { <action> } segments where you perform the action if the condition is true. There's a default condition of "true" and a default action of "print $0" so all 5 of these expressions are equivalent: '1 == 1 { print $0 }', '{print $0}', '1 == 1', '{print}', '1' and each would simply print the current record.

Comment: I understand that ending a expression with / mean {print $0}   and that ~ must be equal to == right?  but why did you wrap your pattern [x] in / 's ?

Comment: You misunderstand the meaning of "/" and "~". /../ are the delimiters for a constant regular expression. "~" is the regular expression operator and can be applied to constant REs, or variables containing REs or RE strings. All of those are conditions and so are completely unrelated to {print $0} which is an action.

Comment: I recommend you get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins" (http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/awkprog3/) as it explains all of this. In the meantime, while you wait for it to arrive, the text for it is online at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html.

Answer (score 0):

In somewhat the same order, what would be a simple `awk`-rule to keep only the lines that don't have sth in one field and simultaneously sth else in another field? Possibly with a pattern.

e.g.:

A=1 B=2 C=3
B=2 E=5 C=3
A=1 D=4 C=3

A line like this

```
awk '$1$3 != "A=1""C=3" {print $0}' IN > OUT
```

seems to do the trick,
and the moment I start to use the `&&`-operator (in a bash script) `awk` tends to delete all the lines that contain A=1 OR C=3. But the goal is to keep the middle line.

I would like to tell `awk` to delete line one and three when field one contains the letter, the sub-string 'A' and field three the letter 'C' simultaneously.

But, `awk` doesn't want to listen to me or I'm seriously doing sth wrongly (as I'm still in the experimental `awk`-phase)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32309589)